# mysql date shows 30/11/-000 instead of 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, date

I know this is already asked but I can't find a correct answer also because my problem is a little different.

I have a web app written in php with mysql. Everything works fine over the past years until some days ago I moved  the app to a new much performing server, the source and the db. Everything run smoothly but not in this date case.

The wrong date is saved on a mysql table with `0000-00-00` but when I show it appears `30/11/-000`

How to get rid off this? I still have the old working server so I can check for mysql or php configuration. I think the problem is simple as a configuration parameter, but I can't find the right one.

This is the snippet for retreiving the date. This is not my code, and can't ask to the original developer, can you explain me why there is a check if the date is 30/11/1999? Seems a common problem google says, and I think is involved.

```
    function getDataF($data){

       if (($stadata = strtotime($data)) == -1 || $stadata === false) {
           return "";
       }

       $return = date("d/m/Y",$stadata);

       if ($return == "30/11/1999") return "";

       return $return;

}
```

Comment: 30/11/-000 is not a valid date format for mysql u need to convert it to Y-m-d format before saving to DB

Comment: Please provide the PHP and SQL calling the data.

Comment: I can't debug remotely, because on my local environment works right. @AbhikChakraborty the date is saved on mysql like 0000-00-00.
Updated question

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html - check out DATE_FORMAT, it's cool and doesn't screw up database indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtotime returns `30/11/1999` when the input is `00-00-00 00:00:00`. [Code Pad here](http://codepad.org/IqKmL0g0). This explains why developer checked if the date is 30/11/1999 and return empty in that case.

Regarding why `0000-00-00` dates displayed as `31/11/-000`: It seems there is a bug (or "feature") in strtotime function that it returns `-0001` as year for some PHP versions ([example here](https://www.php.net/strtotime#108673)). So, for your invalid dates, date results in `31/11/-0001`. I guess the code that display dates strips one character from the end as it expects year as 4 digits.

Comment: Ok thanks but the year is already saved in this format of 4 digits. I don't know why I have this problem only for changing server, the mysql and php are the same versions.

Comment: Where the year is saved? I thought it is just displayed (not saved) after going through `getDataF` function.

Comment: getdataF converts the date format and display it from sql record. I add at the if stantment that if I get 30/11/1999 or 30/11/-000 return blank.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's nothing stopping the script at your `if` statements (assuming that's your intention), so it outputs at the end whatever `$return` is no matter what.

You either need some `else` statements or some `exit()` or `die()` functions to stop the train if one of your conditions are met.

Also, your first condition is calling the variable `$stadata` after the `||` operator before it's defined. Why do you need this extra variable anyway? Just test if `$data` exists or not. Plus, you need to further parse your input.

If you don't need `$stadata` later on, just do this:

```
function getDataF($data){

   if (!$data) {
       return "";
   } 
   else
   {
    $return = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data));

       if ($return == "30/11/1999") { 
        return "";
       } 
       else
       {
         return $return;
       }
   }
}
```

This is quick and dirty, not the most efficient way to write it, but will do the job.

Comment: I don't understand, the code will exit after every if, there is a return, no need to use die() or exit() or else instead.

Answer (score 0):

You would have probably moved from a 32bit server to 64 bit.

[strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) works as expected only on a 32bit server. The manual says

[image: Behavior of strtotime on 64 bit machines.]

`strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')` returns `31/11/-000` based on your timezone. 
The original developer probably wanted to cover this case if the code was moved to a 64bit server and had this check.